# How are CAN Identifier value assigned in CAN communication?

Tags: can

I am trying to learn CAN protocol and came across CAN Identifier(CAN ID) ,From my understanding CAN ID talks about the priority of message and message type and it is used to win arbitration.
then, what is NODE ID in can network ? Is it part of the can identifier itself which gives information about the source of the message in the network?

How does the receiver know the type of message and who is the sender of the message ?

What information does the 11 bit ID gives the receiver? that is what information is filled in the 11 bit-ID field? Can some explain with a real time example?

Does CAN identifier has anything to do with the number of nodes/ecu connected in a network?
Out of the 0 to 7FF message ID, are some of the identifier fixed for some specific application or is it proprietary we decide as per our project?

Any feedback would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

CAN co-mingles the message ID and priority. Message IDs imply the priority, but have no other low-level meaning if you look only at the basic CAN protocol layer 1 and 2 given in ISO 11898-1 (with very few exceptions).

This makes sense when you think of the applications of CAN: always relatively small networks, where each node is quite constrained in what it expects from other nodes, and how it behaves. This allows flexibility in choosing complexity of a higher-level network. E.g. in industrial applications you may need a network that interoperates with arbitrary devices from multiple vendors, and each network may be different - you'll want a higher level protocol that imposes lots of "order" on the meaning of individual messages, so that e.g. some PLC device can make sense of it all without having to hard-code the details of communication with each type of a device. Otherwise, for applications where the network structure is relatively fixed (but still may be extended in the future without breaking anything), you can choose to be in charge of it all and act more ad-hoc. Don't overengineer!

> How does the receiver know the type of message

The basic CAN protocol is not enough to fully specify that. A higher-level protocol defines such things. If you're implementing a network of "raw" CAN devices, you'll have a table in the firmware that assigns meaning to various message IDs, and that table will be shared among all devices (usually a header file shared among firmware sources). The higher-level protocol is thus authored by you. Or you may choose some existing protocol.

> [How does the receiver know] who is the sender of the message ?

The basic CAN protocol doesn't handle that. A higher-level protocol may add information about the originator of the message. If you design that protocol, it's up to you to add that information. Raw CAN messages simply don't carry this information.

In simple ad-hoc networks, there's a n:1 relationship between the message identifier and the message source, i.e. one message source may send multiple message IDs, but for any message ID there's only one source. Suppose you have a stepper motor driver and a shaft position encoder. The encoder may have a message ID meaning "Shaft Angle 1", and since there's only one shaft and one encoder, that message ID identifies the encoder device. Similarly, some master device will have the "Stepper Motor 1 Position Setpoint" message ID: this message is associated with the unique master device, but also with the consumer - the stepper driver - that knows to expect such a message and act upon it. When you are writing firmware for all nodes, this is easy to define ad-hoc and evolve as the system grows. When you interoperate with other devices, ad-hoc approaches break down rather quickly, and a bit more structure is then desired.

> Does CAN identifier has anything to do with the number of nodes/ecu connected in a network?

No. Depending on what higher-level protocol is used on top of raw CAN, the message identifier may have also to do with the purpose of the message.

In "ad-hoc" networks, an identifier may be assigned to a particular variable broadcast by a particular sensor.

Say, there are 3 temperature sensors on the network. They may all broadcast with a message id meaning "TEMPERATURE", and then inside the message there'd be a field that discriminates which particular sensor sent that information. Alternatively, the 3 temperature sensors may each use their own message-id to broadcast that information, e.g. TEMPERATURE1 would be a different message-id than TEMPERATURE2 or TEMPERATURE3.

Furthermore, since the message ids determine the priority, if a measured value is "more important" than some other value, it would have an id with higher priority.

Higher level protocols such as CANopen impose structure on the message identifiers, but that's out of scope of the raw CAN protocol. E.g. some "master" on the network may enumerate other devices that all react to broadcast messages with a certain ID and reply with their information, and that master may then tell each device what message ID to use for either sending the measured data or listening for setpoints (in actuators), and how often to send the measured value - in case of sensors, of how often to expect the setpoint value - in case of actuators - and how to react when the new setpoint value is not timely, i.e. what is the timeout, and what to do when it expires (e.g. stay at the current setpoint, or go to some failsafe setpoint, or turn the torque output off etc.).

> Out of the 0 to 7FF message ID, are some of the identifier fixed for some specific application or is it proprietary we decide as per our project?

In all cases, you'll choose a higher level protocol that rides on top of raw CAN. That protocol determines the measning of each message ID.

Such a protocol may be ad-hoc and simple, with one message ID assigned for each variable a sensor may be monitoring, or each setpoint some source may be sending to an actuator - that'd be the "proprietary" option. Otherwise, a protocol like CANopen will specify exactly what identifiers serve what purpose, and such protocols often have a "master" that uses fixed message IDs only for initial system setup, and then assigns each slave device a particular set of message IDs it will be using to send or receive data when the network transitions from the configuration state to operational state.

---

It's also worth saying that CAN-derived protocols don't always run on the CAN physical layer. As the industrial and also in-car networks converge on the Ethernet physical layer, the investments in higher level CAN protocols are re-used, and the same CAN messages are simply sent on top of a different physical layer, with slightly different semantics. E.g. in a car you may have CAN traffic sent on top of two-wire 100BASE-T1 network (IEEE 802.3bw). In an industrial application, you may have CAN traffic sent as CoE - CAN-over-EtherCAT, on top of the EtherCAT protocol running over a 100BASE-TX network, for example. It's worth mentioning that industrial CoE deployments often vastly exceed that capacity of the 11898-1 physical medium and may include thousands or even tens of thousands of nodes.

---

> Say for example in a car where we are use Classic CAN 2.0A protocol, the driver pressed AC on/off or fan on/off button this information has to go the HVAC controller and status need to be delivered back to the Button module and also the display module. How to frame the can id ? Can you give an example of the frame or CAN ID structure ? How does the HVAC know which button module is pressed or to which button it should send ?

This depends on what actual protocol runs on top of the CAN layer 2. If it's something ad-hoc, then the button will send a frame with CAN ID meaning `HVAC_BUTTON_PRESSED` - it doesn't even need any contents. The HVAC controller listens for it, and reacts by toggling the A/C state. It then broadcasts a frame with `HVAC_AC_STATE_CHANGED`. The parties don't magically "know" what CAN message ID means what: they literally have this embedded in the firmware as a table derived from the file that describes the total design of the in-car network. Such a file would have all the message types included, and each node's firmware would be programmed with an excerpt of the table that pertains to it. If you don't have such modeling tools, you just share the `.h` files :)

If you're doing the entire design yourself, you have complete freedom with regards to what IDs to allocate. You're the architect of the level 3+ protocol that way.

You should notice by now that from the point of the receiving node, it doesn't matter *who* is sending a message. The `HVAC_BUTTON_PRESSED` message should only ever be sent by the button having that function... or maybe also by an integrated display, and don't forget the diagnostic tool. What matters is that someone sent a message, and any node interested in that message will react to it. The HVAC controller doesn't need to know nor should it care where the message is from: something connected to the network had broadcast the message, and it's its job to react to it.

Same goes for the button: it doesn't care who sent an update of the A/C state. The button's job is to indicate, on its LED, the state of the A/C. When someone sends a message indicating this, the button reacts. The button could also react to a different message - `HVAC_AC_BUTTON_LED_OVERRIDE`. That message could be sent by the body controller as a part of the power-up self test of indicators (i.e. all lights come on when you start the car, and then turn off). It could also be sent by a diagnostic tool to verify the button's functionality. That way any other modules that act based on A/C state wouldn't be fed incorrect data.

Again, all those message IDs are completely up to the implementer of the higher-level protocol, and that would be you if you chose to set it all up yourself.

[image: Interaction diagram of the user, button, its LED, and the HVAC controller]